# elasticsearch high disk watermark

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I have elasticsearch running as a container on a local system.

I would like to know how elasticsearch calculates available space on disk.
[image]
In my case, I have almost 14 GB of free space on the disk. However, according to the information appearing in the console, 2.8 GB remains.

```
{
   "type":"server",
   "timestamp":"2024-01-30T06:28:53,667Z",
   "level":"WARN",
   "component":"o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor",
   "cluster.name":"docker-cluster",
   "node.name":"2ed67e4dfbcd",
   "message":"high disk watermark [97%] exceeded on [ropWHCL_RIOwvoIJYQQoVg][2ed67e4dfbcd][/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0] free: 2.8gb[1.5%], shards will be relocated away from this node; currently relocating away shards totalling [0] bytes; the node is expected to continue to exceed the high disk watermark when these relocations are complete",
   "cluster.uuid":"aR-yv9mmTOOmDPlDXs_ZJQ",
   "node.id":"ropWHCL_RIOwvoIJYQQoVg"
}
```

The second thing is. During use, I noticed that this amount of space was constantly decreasing. At the beginning, after installing elasticserch, it informed me about 9 GB of free space. And now, as I wrote, it has 2.8gb. Interestingly, the index itself is only 44mb, so where does the disk space go?

my docker-compose config:

```
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.16.3
    container_name: ${PROJECT_NAME}_elasticsearch
    volumes:
      - ./.docker/elasticsearch/data:/var/lib/elastic/data
    environment:
      - "discovery.type=single-node"
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1g -Xmx1g"
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=pass

    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    ports:
      - "${ELASTICSEARCH_PORT}:9200"
```